# How to remove htmltags in word document that downloaded from ckeditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

[image: RESULT]Hi Guys i am using  Ckeditor i am downloading the data typed in editor as word doc but in the downloaded word document file the html  tags are displaying , how to disable the html tags

my config code

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
config.undoStackSize = 90;
    config.width = "98%";

    config.height = "400px";

    config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,image,flash,iframe,link,smiley,tabletools,find,pagebreak,templates,about,maximize,showblocks,newpage,language';

    config.removeButtons = 'Copy,Cut,Paste,Undo,Redo,Print,Form,TextField,Textarea,Button,SelectAll,NumberedList,BulletedList,CreateDiv,Table,Select,HiddenField,Source,Checkbox, Radio Button,Preview';

    config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
    config.allowedContent = true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `config` this:

```
config.autoParagraph = false;
```

Comment: i used config.autoParagraph = false; not working still tags are displaying

Comment: Can you update your code to see what you have, and if possible to share how's the result you're getting so you can receive a better answer